# Can I change the colors of individual Node Group headers (not the theme)?

Tags: node-editor, interface

It would be helpful to organize my Node Groups by color, for recognition of function at a glance. Changing the theme in application preferences would change all of the headers and prevent  this sort of organization. While I can still organize by color by using the background color, I'm nitpicking.

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Hi :). It's hidden in settings, right next to other node colors.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the reply! I'm not sure what you mean by settings. I've looked in the application preferences and can change all of the Node Group headers to the same color, but I wouldn't be able to *organize* them by color. I'm looking for a way to change individual Node Group headers--not the theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik you cannot change the header color individually. This color is meant to represent the category of the node. Thus organizing them by header color like you want would defeat the purpose. As a workaround you can add a *frame* around the node and colorize that. Right-click any node(s) and select `Join in New Frame`. You can click-select a frame like a node and the options to the right side are now for the frame, including color.

[image]

Comment: This is a nice workaround, though just because Blender devs employed one design principle shouldn't mean a user shouldn't be allowed to change the convention of color consistency to own liking. I wonder if maybe Python could be used to change the color, but we probably would have seen this (ab)used already if it was possible.

Comment: Thank you, Taiyo. I thought this was the case. This is the workaround I currently use. However, changing the header wouldn't defeat the purpose of organizing by color, because I create node groups that would effectively fit into existing categories and want to change NG headers for that exact purpose. Furthermore, multiple Node Groups can serve different purposes and be nested like stacking dolls, so it can be confusing to know, at a glance, where you are in complicated trees. Cheers!

Comment: Yea, its not that i wouldnt like to see that feature too. I did not find anything header changeable on Python side though.